# Unable to send message to parent process after multiple forks

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

I have a program that forks off four processes and calls execlp() to run different code for the child. I pass the child a number as an id. So far, all the child does is try to pass the id back to the parent process. The pipes work, if i put a string though the stream it prints out in the parent process. However, when i try to put the id as an int thought the stream, it does not work. I dont even get to the line of code after the fprintf() and fflush() command in the child.

I made some changes for how i created the file descriptors and added more code for an example. Now, in the child, i am unable to create the FILE* out. However, if i create out on file descriptor 1, it does print to the screen. I tried creating out on file descriptor 3 and the program just sits there and waits for input from the child that never comes.

Here is my parent:

```
Mom::Mom():childCount(0)
{
    pipeCount = fileCount = 0;
    int fd[2];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int c=0; c<NUMJOBS; ++c) jobs[c] = newJob();
    //createFileDescriptors(fd);
    ret = pipe(fd);
    if(ret < 0) fatal("Error creating pipes");
    //cout << fd[0] << "\t"  << fd[1] << endl;
    pipes[fileCount++] = fdopen(fd[0], "r");
    fcntl( 3, F_SETFD, 0 );
    //close(fd[1]);
    //for(int c=3; c<FILEDESCRIPTORS; c+=2) pipes[pipeCount++] = fdopen(c, "w");
    createChildren();
    for(int c=0; c<4; c++)
    {
        int tmp = -1;
        //cout << "About to read from children, tmp = " << tmp << endl;
        ret = fscanf(pipes[0], "%d", &tmp);
        //char* buffer = (char*) malloc(80*sizeof(char));
        //char buffer[80];
        //read(3, buffer, 80);
        cout << ret << "\t" << tmp << endl;
        //cout << ret << " " << tmp << endl;
        //free(buffer);
    }
    //sleep(5);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Create all the children by using fork() and execlp()
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Mom::createChildren()
{
    int fd[2];
    fcntl( fd[IN], F_SETFD, 0 );
    for(int c=0; c<NUMCHILDREN; c++)
    {
        ret = pipe(fd);
        if(ret < 0) fatal("Error creating pipes");
        int pid = fork();
        //cout << pid << endl;
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            setupChild(c, fd);
        }
        else
        {
            //close(fd[1]);

        }
    }
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  set up the child and call exec to run ChildMain
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Mom::setupChild(int count, int fd[])
{
    //cout << "Creating child with id: " << count << endl;
    char cnt = '0' + count;
    string id_str (&cnt + '\0');
    fcntl( fd[0], F_SETFD, 0 );
    pipes[fileCount++] = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
    //execlp("ChildMain", "ChildMain",  id_str.c_str(), NULL);
    execlp("ChildMain",  id_str.c_str(), NULL);
}
```

And here is the child code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //cout << argv[argc-1] << endl;
    if(argc < 1) fatal("Not enough arguments provided to ChildMain");
    int id = atoi(argv[argc-1]);
    //cout << *argv[1] << " " << id << endl;
    //redirect STDIN and STDOUT
    /*int c_in = dup(0);
    close(0);
    dup((2*id) + 5);
    int c_out = dup(1);
    close(1);
    dup(4);*/
    /////////////////////////////
    //Child kid((int) *argv[1]);
    FILE* out = fdopen(4, "w");
    if(out == NULL)
        cout << "Error opening stream to parent in child: " << id << endl;
    //char childID = '0' + id;
    //char buf[80];
    //strcpy(buf, "Child ");
    //strcat(buf, &childID);
    string buf ("Child");
    //cout << tmp << " " << childID << endl;
    //write(4, buf.c_str(), buf.length()+1);
    //cout << id << endl;
    int ret = fprintf(out, "%d", id);
    fflush(out);
    //fclose(out);
    //cout << id << " " << ret << endl;
    //ch.push_back((char) id);
    //put STDIN and STDOUT back to correct file descriptors
    /*close(1);
    dup(c_out);
    close(0);
    dup(c_in);*/
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return 0;
}
```

I am very confused why this works for the first child, with id 0, but no the others. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the expected result, and what do you get?

Comment: In the code where i read from the child, the first iteration of the for loop prints "1 0" (1 being the return from fscanf and 0 being the first child's id). On the next three iterations, it prints (-1 -1). The expected result is : 1 0, 1 1, 1 2, 1 3.  In the child code, the print right after the fflush(out) statement, for child with id 0, it prints 0 1. The children with ids 1, 2, 3 do not execute this statement or it does not make it to the screen.

Comment: Are you certain that the pipe will always be file descriptor `4` in all the child processes? Can you somehow attach a debugger to one of the failing child processes?

Comment: The only certainty i have now is that i do an fdopen(4, "w"). Since i create the pipe in the parent before the fork, this leads me to believe that the pipe will be on file descriptor 4. I can do some debugging later when i am at my computer with my code on it.

Comment: Regarding the file descriptor number, that's not true at all. Since you create the file descriptors in the parent, they get different numbers in the parent, and are then inherited (_without_ renumbering) in the children. The normal thing to do is actually to close `FILENO_STDIN` and `FILENO_STDOUT` (the file descriptors for `stdin` and `stdout`) and call [`dup2`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dup2) in the children do make the pipes the new `FILENO_STDIN` and `FILENO_STDOUT`.

Comment: So the normal thing for me to do would to redirect stdout to file descriptor 4 which was created in the parent? I don't understand how that is different than writing to file descriptor 4 in the child and reading from file descriptor 3 in the parent?

Answer (score 0):

`execlp(3)` is expecting null terminated strings as it's args. `&cnt` won't be null terminated.

Simple fix:

```
void Mom::setupChild(int count, int fd[])
{
    char cnt[2];
    cnt[0] = '0' + count;
    cnt[1] = '\0';
    fcntl( fd[(2*count)+3], F_SETFD, 0 );
    execlp("ChildMain", "ChildMain",  &cnt, NULL);
}
```

This doesn't scale to 10 processes though, so I'd probably use a buffer and just sprintf() into it.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. It still only works for the first child created but all the other children created do not send the id back to the parent.

Comment: try making the first child's ID=1 to see if it is a problem with the id number or related to the fact ther are multiple children. Also your read from child loop always reads pipes[0] - is this in a bigger loop so it is using a different versionof pipes each time?

Comment: I tried starting at ID=1, and the first one prints 1 1 followed by four lines of -1 -1. Whats interesting is that i have a for loop that calls my setupChild function that is only supposed to create four children. I will have to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example on how to implement the suggestion in my comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    /* Need two sets of pipes: one for child stdin, one for child stdout */
    int pipefds1[2];
    int pipefds2[2];

    pipe(pipefds1);
    pipe(pipefds2);

    int rc = fork();
    if (rc == -1)
        perror("fork");
    else if (rc == 0)
    {
        /* In child */

        /* Close the old stdin and stdout */
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);

        /* Create new stdin/stroud from the pipes */
        dup2(pipefds1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipefds2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        /* Close the unneeded pipe handles */
        close(pipefds1[1]);
        close(pipefds2[0]);

        /* Now pass control to the new program */
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "/", NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        /* In parent */

        /* Close the uneeded pipe handles */
        close(pipefds1[0]);
        close(pipefds2[1]);

        /* We want to use stdio functions */
        FILE *fp = fdopen(pipefds2[0], "r");

        /* Read all from the child */
        char buffer[128];
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
        {
            printf("Input from child: %s\n", buffer);
        }

        fclose(fp);

        /* Wait for child to exit */
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully this will be enough for you to build on.

The error handling is non-existant, but it is tested.